# Why is volatileWrite necessary inside Atomic{Type}Array constructor

Tags: java.util.concurrent, java, java-memory-model

For example the constructor that takes array size of java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLongArray is defined as following:

```
    public AtomicLongArray(int length) {
    array = new long[length];
    // must perform at least one volatile write to conform to JMM
    if (length > 0)
        unsafe.putLongVolatile(array, rawIndex(0), 0);
}
```

Snippet taken from [AtomicLongArray.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.java#AtomicLongArray.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29).

Why is volatileWrite necessary inside this constructor when array field is final ?

Comment: Perhaps the [`JavaMemoryModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) had a quirk so at least 1 write was required: `A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.`

Comment: @S.D. If we assume that array is not final would this code ensure that no other CPU sees value of array as null when constructor finishes?

Comment: No outside code should be able to reference it before the constructor finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for it, and this line of code was removed in later versions of of the JDK

This how it looks in JDK 1.7 and 1.8

```
public  AtomicLongArray(int length) {
     array = new long[length];
}
```

Comment: Oh yes I found it in newer versions it says: // Visibility guaranteed by final field guarantees